# Windows can't run python script from within eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse

I'm on a Windows machine and using Eclipse.
My java code is invoking a python script by using :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c e:\\dev\\CodeBase\\WebService\\src\\com\\rest\\service\\PythonScript.py");
```

On running the code it opens the prompt for choosing a program to run the script with. What can I do to make it run implicitly?

Comment: Check your PATH for env. variables. If you have Python in the path already, then prefix `python ` to the path of your script; not cmd /c. It should like like `python my_scriptpath.py` in your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running Python interpreter instead:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("[PATH TO YOUR PYTHON DIR]\\python.exe e:\\dev\\CodeBase\\WebService\\src\\com\\rest\\service\\PythonScript.py");
```

Usually `[PATH TO YOUR PYTHON DIR]` is something like `C:\\Python27\\` or `C:\\Python34` depending on your Python version.

If you have Python directory added to your system `PATH` variable sole `.exec("python ...")` will suffice.

Comment: That prompt doesn't come up now. But my output is blank. My .py file is simple - 
    def main():
    return "Hello World".
Is this right?

Comment: @Natasha No, this script won't do nothing. But it shouldn't be any problem for you to fix it: try searching "hello world in python" via google and you'll find lots of examples. You might want to add `input()` (or `raw_input()` for Python2) call at the end, so the window won't disappear immediately.

Comment: I didnt get that part. what input?

Comment: @Natasha So it will wait for the user to press the "enter" key, before the window disappears. It's not essential, if you see the console view in Eclipse after the program finishes - if yes, disregard that part. Otherwise, the script will run very fast, and the console will disappear before you will be able to see anything.

Comment: I'm using the Eclipse console.

Comment: I tried the following python code, the output is still blank:
#!/usr/bin/python
import json

def hello():
 obj = "Hello World"
 jsonString = json.dumps(obj)
 
 print jsonString
 
hello()

Comment: @Natasha Why haven't you tried my advice about looking into the search engine to find working examples of "hello world" Python scripts?

Comment: I did, I tried this too, its the same output.

#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
mystring = sys.argv[0]
print mystring

This is working for someone else.

Comment: @Natasha Please try to actually read the tutorial and try to understand what the script does. Try this one: [click](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Hello,_World!), just `print "Hello world"` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the .py file to .exe use Py2Exe. You can download it and follow the instructions to convert it.